# Hexadecimal search by JS test function and replacing it with some value

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a hexadecimal regex pattern to identify and replace  a hexadecimal value in a string with some fixed value. But it is neither identifying it with the test function nor is it replacing it. The regex pattern seems to be OK as per my need. Please advise.

```
 function test_replace() {
    var str = '22:03705081:Xx1aB5c';
    var patrn = /[\x00-\x1f\x22\x5c]/g;
    if (patrn.test(str))
    return str.replace(patrn, 'hexa')
    else
    return str
 }

 test_replace();
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the **input** and **desired** output

Comment: Your regex only matches ASCII control chars, `"` and ``\``. Your string does not contain them.

Comment: Assign result back to `str`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Does part of pattern "[\x00-\x1f]" would not match 00 to 1f range 31 hexadecimal value range and also "22" and 5c hexadecimal values present in any string

Comment: Yes, but your input string has no such characters. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lcokqhm/2/). You do not even need `.test()` part, `.replace()` returns the same string if no match is found.

Comment: Lets assume string is '22:03705081:Xx1aB5c'.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Please keep in mind that I want to identify a specific hexadecimal characters range in my string and neither test function is returning true nor replace.

Comment: Your `22:03705081:Xx1aB5c` string contains digits, colons and letters. It does not contain control chars, nor `"` nor ``\``.

Comment: but hexadecimal/base 16 string is combination of 0–9 and a-f letters only. Probably,you are talking about ASCII character counterparts of these hexadecimal values.

Comment: If you want to match a pair of a digit/letter from `a` to `f`, you would use `/[\da-f]{2}/ig`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Appology for bothering you again and again.Could you please explain what my mentioned pattern would look for? I have impression that it should check 34(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,1f,22,5c) hexadecimal values through these 2 js functions like "\da-f" in pattern would check character a,b,c,d,e,f and digits combination.

Comment: This is [what your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/QGex84/1). [More info](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%00%01%02%03%04%05%06%07%08%09%10%1A%1B%1C%1D%1E%1F%22%5C) here.

Comment: Perhaps, you need [`/1[0-9a-f]|22|5c|[0-9a-f]/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/QGex84/4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`[\x00-\x1f\x22\x5c]` regex](https://regex101.com/r/QGex84/1) matches ASCII characters with hex codes from `00` till `1F` (control chars) and also a `22` and `5C` chars (`"` and `\` respectively).

If you plan to match *strings* like `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `1‌​8`, `19`, `1a`, `1b`, `1c`, `1d`, `1e`,‌ `​1f`, `22`, `5c` use

```
/22|5c|1?[0-9a-f]/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BXnpDk/2).

**Details**:

- `22` - `22`
- `|` - or
- `5c` - `5c`
- `|`  - or
- `1?[0-9a-f]` - an optional (1 or 0 times) `1` followed with any digit or letter from `a` till `f`.

```js
function test_replace(str) {
    var patrn = /22|5c|1?[0-9a-f]/gi;
    return str.replace(patrn, 'hex');
 }

console.log(test_replace('22:03705081:Xx1aB5c'));
```